# Angular directive link functions onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics-api

I am building an AngularJS directive like this. I want to make a reusable widget that can extract data from Google Analytics and create a gauge chart, but I am stuck at the first step.

```
dashboardApp.directive('organicSearchGauge', function() {
return {
    scope: {
        color: '='
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div id="xxx"></div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var clientId;
        var apiKey = 'xxx'
        var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        } ...
```

The following functions are auth2.0 and making the API call, and I was supposed to write the data I get from the GA into `<div id="xxx></div>`.

In the HTML file, I have a `<script>` like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

so that I can load GA API library and start the handleClientLoad() function. But the directive does not work.

I guess the problem is the first `handleClientLoad()`, because I inserted a `Document.ElemenyByID().innerHTML` to test whether this function works and it turns out that it doesn't. So I guess that the "onLoad=" in `<script>` tag doesn't work at all? Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Google API looks the function attached to window object you need to create the function in window scope. Use dependency injection into your directive to get **$window** object reference and create function in window object scope. Also use **$timeout** which is angular way of handling timeout.

```
dashboardApp.directive('organicSearchGauge', ['$window', '$timeout', function($window, $timeout) {
return {
    scope: {
        color: '='
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div id="xxx"></div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var clientId;
        var apiKey = 'xxx'
        var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

        $window.handleClientLoad = function () {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            $timeout(function(){
               checkAuth();
            }, 1);
        } 
        .....
     }
  }

}]);
```

Comment: I have some other functions that link to the handleClientLoad(), should I add $window. prefix to all of them? Thank you.

Comment: no need to add $window prefix to the functions linking to handleClientLoad() because google API will look for handleClientLoad() alone which should be in window scope. Feel free to mark it as correct answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have revised my directive as your instruction. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29RMr/3/) But it turns out that the directive stops running once again at $window.handleClientLoad. Would you mind helping me with this? I am so confused with the Angular way... Thank you...

Comment: Thanks you Subash. I have tried your code, but unfortunately it still doesn't works. I can't see anything in the console. My origin code without injecting $window service do works sometimes, displaying the gauge successfully after refresh sometimes and fail again after refresh. I found that it is because the browser load GA js first and directive.js later. After first load, the browser will load js files in the cache, so that the directive file is loaded before GA file. Then I set a ?version= trick to force the browser load directive js file every time. It works for now..

Answer (score 0):

`handleClientLoad` is a private function. As a quick fix, add `window.handleClientLoad = handleClientLoad` to your link function.

Comment: Thank you. It inspired me that I solved this problem by adding a `window.onLoad = handleClientLoad()`.